# ModuleNotFoundError: No module names src

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, compiler-errors, package

I have setup my project as following:

```
myProject
    src
        __init__.py
        connections.py
        properties.py
        node.py
    __init__.py
    test
        test.py
```

Property and Connection classes are imported in 'node.py' as described below:

```
 from src.properties import Property
 from src.connections import Connection
```

When I try to compile node.py using the command 'python3 node.py', I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should try executing the code from the root directory, i.e, myProject folder

Comment: use `from .properties import Property`

Comment: @hadi I tried it from the myProject folder with 'python3 src/connections.py' but I am getting the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.properties'; '__main__' is not a package.

Comment: @ChayanBansal I am getting the same error